# Change of Variables in Partial Derivatives - Multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, divergence-operator

So I am trying to solve the divergence of F

$$ 
{F(x, y, z) = z \mathbf i + y \mathbf j + x \mathbf k} \\\\
{\nabla F(x, y, z) = {\partial z \over \partial x} + {\partial y \over \partial y} + {\partial x \over \partial z}}
$$

which is 1.

But when I do a change to spherical coordinates, so

$$ {x = \rho\sin \phi \cos \theta}, {y = \rho\sin \phi \sin \theta}, {z = \rho \cos \phi}
$$

For ${\partial z \over \partial x}$ I am getting

$$ {\partial z \over \partial x} = {\partial z \over \partial \rho} {\partial \rho \over \partial x} + {\partial z \over \partial \phi} {\partial \phi \over \partial x} + {\partial z \over \partial \theta} {\partial \theta \over \partial x} = {cos \phi \over\sin \phi cos \theta} - {\sin \phi \over \cos \phi \cos \theta}$$

Shouldn't this equate to 0?

May I ask what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivatives for $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$ are wrong. Here is the correct derivation:

$$\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \to \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} = \sin\phi \cos\theta$$

$$\phi = \arccos\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \to \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{z^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}} \cdot -\frac{xz}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$ = \frac{xz}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)} = \frac{\cos\theta \cos\phi}{\rho}$$

Using these derivatives, we get $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = (\cos\phi)(\sin\phi \cos\theta) + (-\rho\sin\phi)(\frac{\cos\theta \cos\phi}{\rho}) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!